# The change in the file is not accepted

Tags: java, android

I'm making changes to order.java

```
public Integer getId() {
return id;
                       }

 public void setId(Integer id) {
 this.id = id;
                                }

public Integer getCustomerId() {
return customerId;
                               }

public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
this.customerId = customerId;
                                          }

public Integer getStatus() {
return status;
 }

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
this.status = status;
      }

public String getCreatedAt() {
return createdAt;
       }

public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
```

This is my original code.

Build > Make project

```
public Integer getId() {
return id;
    }

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
                       }

public Integer getCustomerId() {
return customerId;
       }

public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
this.customerId = customerId;
                }

public Integer getStatus() {
return status;
         }

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
this.status = status;
            }

public String getCreatedAt() {
return createdAt;
            }

public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
this.createdAt = createdAt;
          }

 public Integer getId() {
return this.id;
 }

 public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
  }
```

Adding to the bottom line

```
public Integer getId() {
return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
   }
```

Why does it add code under the order.java file? I cannot edit any of my files.

**I usually get this error:**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:greendao'.
>
> Found 4 problem(s) parsing
>   "D:\Android\wonder\app\src\main\java\net\arshimet\wonder\data\db\model\Order.java".
>   First problem: Pb(355) Duplicate method getId() in type Order
>   (67109219 at line 46). Run gradle with --info for more details.

Comment: are you using any kind of annotation for getter/setters to be generated? It just looks like the second `getId()` is generated (it uses `return this.id`) while the first one does not use the `this.`. Are they some kind of "entities" in a DB framework? Then it could be that the framework wants to generate at least the `id` getter and setters.

Comment: Is your class file extending or implementing any other class/interface? Although in that case it would have generated overriden annotation as well. One quick fix would be to try deleting getter setter which are generated. Also could you show us how id field (private member) is declared..